# Given a graph find a spanning tree which is not minimum

Tags: data-structures, graph, minimum-spanning-tree, spanning-tree

How to find a spanning tree which is not minimum in a graph(if possiblr)

Answer (score 0):

[Kruskal algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal's_algorithm) finds the minimum spanning tree ordering all the edges by weight, choosing them from the lightest to the heaviest and adding them to the solution only if they don't form a cycle. When you reach a number of edges equal to the number of vertexes minus one, you have the minimum spanning tree.

To obtain a spanning tree that is not minimum you can just apply the same algorithm without pre-ordering the edges' list, or shuffling randomly the list before starting.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to find any arbitrary spanning tree, regardless of whether it's minimal, you can always just use a plain vanilla DFS or BFS to search the graph, building up the spanning tree by adding in edges to newly-discovered nodes. This runs in time linear in the size of the graph, is fast in practice, and is simple to code up.

If your goal is to find a spanning tree that specifically isn't an MST, you could consider just running a regular MST algorithm, but when comparing weights on edges, always reverse the result of the comparison. This ends up finding a *maximum* spanning tree, which, unless every spanning tree in the graph happens to be minimum, won't be a minimum spanning tree. This takes the same amount of time as running a regular MST algorithm, so you can take your pick on which one you'd like to use.